How many cycle of length $k$ in the wreath product $S_n\wr S_m$?
Let's consider the morphism $S_m\wr S_n\to S_{mn}$. Considered as a subgroup of $S_{mn}$, how many cycle of length $k$ is there in $S_m\wr S_n$, where $0<k<nm$?
NB: I have answered below.

The number of cycle of length $k$
in $S_m\wr S_n$ denoted by $c(n,m,k)$
is
\begin{equation}
c(n,m,k)=
\begin{cases}
1\quad \mbox{ if $k=1$}\\
\frac{n}{k}m_{(k)} \quad \mbox{if $k<= m$}\\
(n-1)!(m-1)! m!^{n-1} \quad \mbox{if $k=mn$}\\
\frac{n_{(r)}}{r}\frac{m!^{r}}{m} \quad \mbox{if $k=mr$ where $2\leq r\leq n-1$}\\
0 \quad \mbox{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
I use symmetric function to prove it,
We have the result that
$$
h_n\circ h_m=\frac{1}{\# S_m\wr S_n}\sum_{g\in S_m\wr S_n} p_{sh(g)}, \quad \mbox{where $sh(g)$ is the shape of $g$ considered as elements of $S_{nm}$.}
$$
It is also known that for all $m\in \mathbb{N}$,
$$
h_n=\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{g\in S_n}p_{sh(g)}=\sum_{\lambda\vdash n} \frac{p_{\lambda}}{z_{\lambda}}.
$$
Then we get
$$
h_n\circ h_m= (\sum_{\lambda\vdash n} \frac{p_{\lambda}}{z_{\lambda}})\circ (\sum_{\lambda\vdash m} \frac{p_{\lambda}}{z_{\lambda}}).
$$
We know that
$$(\sum_{\lambda\vdash n} \frac{p_{\lambda}}{z_{\lambda}})\circ (\sum_{\lambda\vdash m} \frac{p_{\lambda}}{z_{\lambda}})=\sum_{\lambda\vdash n} \frac{p_{\lambda}}{z_{\lambda}}\circ \sum_{\lambda\vdash m}\frac{p_{\lambda}}{z_{\lambda}} $$
If $k\leq m$ the only way to obtain $p_{(k,1^{nm-k})}$ in the plethysm $h_n\circ h_m$ is by the part of the above sum involving
$$
\frac{p_{1^n}}{z_{(1^n)}}\circ \sum_{\lambda\vdash m}\frac{p_{\lambda}}{z_{\lambda}}=\frac{1}{n!}(\sum_{\lambda\vdash m}\frac{p_{\lambda}}{z_{\lambda}})^n
$$
So to obtain $p_{(k,1^{nm-k})}$, we choose one $p_{(k,1^{m-k})}$ and $(n-1)$-times $p_{(1^m)}$. We have $n$-way to do it. Then the coefficients of $p_{(k,1^{nm-k})}$ is equal to
$$
\frac{1}{n!} n\frac{1}{z_{(k,1^{m-k}})}\left( \frac{1}{z_{(1^m)}})\right)^{n-1}=\frac{1}{(n-1)!} \frac{1}{k (m-k)!}\frac{1}{m!^{(n-1)}} 
$$
If $k=mr$, where $2 \leq r\leq n-1$ the only way to obtain $p_{(mr,1^{(mn-mr)})}$ in the plethysm $h_n\circ h_m$ is by the part of the sum above involving
\begin{align}
\frac{p_{(r,1^{n-r})}}{z_{(r,1^{n-r})}}\circ \sum_{\lambda\vdash m}\frac{p_{\lambda}}{z_{\lambda}}&=\frac{1}{r (n-r)!} \left( p_{r}\circ (\sum_{\lambda\vdash m} \frac{p_{\lambda}}{z_{\lambda}})\right). \left(p_{(1^{n-r})}\circ \sum_{\lambda\vdash m} \frac{p_{\lambda}}{z_{\lambda}}\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{r(n-r)!}\left( \sum_{\lambda\vdash m} p_r\circ \frac{p_{\lambda}}{z_{\lambda}} \right).\left( \sum_{\lambda\vdash m} \frac{p_{\lambda}}{z_{\lambda}}\right)^{n-r}.
\end{align}
We are only interested in the $p_{rm}$ term in $\sum_{\lambda\vdash m}p_r\circ \frac{p_{\lambda}}{z_{\lambda}}$. The last equality gives us the coefficients of $p_{(rm,1^{(nm-rm)})}$ in $h_n\circ h_m$, by choosing the $p_{rm}$ and processing to the product by taking each $p_{(1^m)}$, $(n-r)$-times in $\sum_{\lambda\vdash m}\frac{p_{\lambda}}{z_{\lambda}}$. In summary we have, the coefficients of $p_{(rm,1^{nm-rm})}$ is equal to
$$
\frac{1}{r(n-r)!}\frac{1}{z_{(m)}} \left(\frac{1}{z_{(1^m)}}\right)^{n-r}=\frac{1}{r(n-r)!}\frac{1}{m} \left(\frac{1}{m!}\right)^{n-r}=\frac{1}{rm(n-r)! m!^{n-r}}
$$
If $k=nm$, we proceed in the same manner as above. And if $k\geq m$ and $m$ is not a divisor of $k$ then the coefficient of $p_{(k,1^{nm-k})}$ is zero.
We obtain the result by dividing $m!^n n!$ by those coefficients.
